# convert blob to arraybuffer without filereader/xmlttprequest

Tags: javascript, blob, arraybuffer

I want to convert from ArrayBuffer (lets say 100MB) to Blob then back from Blob to ArrayBuffer without duplicating the data.
FileReader / XMLHttpRequest do duplicate the data, so is there an other way?

`var b = new Blob([new Uint8Array(someArrayBuffer)]);`

PS: I want to make cross-tab communication of large  read only buffer without duplicating it, e.g. a local ArrayBuffer is 500MB I want to use it in multiple tabs without duplicating the data.

Comment: I don't think so, no.

Comment: Where is your code ?

Comment: You will always duplicate your data in a `var` or anything else..
`FileReader()` is robust, why you don't want to use it ?

Comment: @pirs i want a reference to it(not duplicate) but from blob object

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Body/arrayBuffer ? Maybe ?

Comment: @pirs: Not in the general case, no. For instance, you can have multiple typed arrays sharing the same underlying `ArrayBuffer`. Also, the question says clearly why he/she doesn't want to use `ArrayBuffer`: It will duplicate the data in the `Blob` rather than just providing a view of it.

Comment: @pirs i just tested it duplicates data as well

Comment: you might be able to use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ArrayBuffer/transfer and Blob.slice() to push/pull together chunks w/o full duplication, since blobs are easy to concat.

Answer (score 1):

There might be ways to convert a Blob to an ArrayBuffer without a FileReader or XHR, but they would all duplicate the data anyway.

But it sounds that what you need is not to convert from a Blob to an ArrayBuffer, but rather to share your ArrayBuffer or Blob across tabs.

For this, you've got multiple ways:

- Store the ArrayBuffer/Blob on the main page, and access it from the children pages directly, like you could access any other global variables:

  ```
  // in parent
  window.myArrayBuffer = buffer;
  ```

  ```
  // in child
  var buf = window.opener.myArrayBuffer;
  doSomethingWithBuffer(buf);
  ```

  #### [Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/ukQXMfTS3BBGls64md7A?p=preview).

- If you need to access the ArrayBuffer only in one tab at a time, then you can transfer its buffer to the other pages, with the `postMessage` API.

  ```
  // in parent
  child.postMessage(myArrayBuffer, 'origin', [myArrayBuffer]);
  // here myArrayBuffer's buffer is *transferred* to child,
  // it can't be accessed by parent anymore
  ```

  ```
  // in child
  window.onmessage = e => {
    buf = e.data;
    ...
  ```

  #### [Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/Ut9WAmY96qkQfyCIMCWk?p=preview).
- If you only need to display a Blob on different but from same-origin windows, then use a blobURI. It will only create a pointer to the data in memory, and lock this data from Garbage Collection until your docs die, but will not duplicate the data.
- If you don't need to support IE nor Safari, you may even consider [SharedWorkers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SharedWorker) on which you will first transfer your ArrayBuffer, and let all your tabs ask it to perform calculations, based on the same data.

Comment: the sharedworkers idea is nice if I use bloburi from different windows I will still need to duplicate the buffer from other window when I want to access the ArrayBuffer of Blob ,Am I right ? because Blob doesn't have a field as buffer

Comment: @user818117 blobURIs are to display/dowload-on-user-disk the data as a file.   Don't use it to share an ArrayBuffer, it makes no sense. Did you missed the first two bullets? To share any variable between same origin frames simply access it. For cross-origin ones, transfer it with postMessage.

Comment: how can I transfer pointer or post message if I want to exchange the buffer pointer between multiple tabs but same origin, not parent or child

Comment: @user818117 from web script, you simply can't, that would be a huge security threat to know what are the other open tabs. From chrome: scripts (extension), then you probably can. But it is way easier for you to simply open these pages from your own script.